# Drag and drop in Weebly editor page through Ruby Watir not working in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir, selenium-firefoxdriver, weebly

I want to drag and drop an element in Weebly editor page through Ruby Watir.

```
drag_from is the element which is to be dragged in editor page
drag_to is the element which is dropped to the editor

drag_from.driver.action.move_to(drag_from.wd).perform
drag_from.fire_event('onmouseup')
drag_to.click
```

The above code works for Chrome, Internet Explorer and Edge browsers. But it doesn't work for Firefox browser.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[This code](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/spec/watirspec/drag_and_drop_spec.rb#L7-L16) is currently working on Watir with Firefox 54 & geckodriver 0.18.0

```
drag_from.drag_and_drop_on drag_to
```

Comment: Need to replace this with first line or first 2 lines?